# Spring security authrorize based on input parameter criteria

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security, authorization

I have a scenario where I need to authorize user based on combination of his permission and input parameter passed.

this is the current scenario

```
public void bookTicket(String bookingType)
    {
    if (bookingType == "AIR"){
         bookAirTicket();
    }else{
         bookBusTicket();
    }
    }


@PreAuthorize("hasRole('BOOK_AIR')")
private void bookAirTicket(){
}

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('BOOK_BUS')")
private void bookBusTicket(){
}
```

Can we have some thing like

```
@PreAuthorize(("hasRole('BOOK_AIR')" AND bookinType='AIR') OR ("hasRole('BOOK_BUS')"  AND bookinType='BUS'))
public void bookTicket(String bookingType)
    {
    if (bookingType == "AIR"){
         bookAirTicket();
    }else{
         bookBusTicket();
    }
    }
```

Basically I need authorization based in input parameters

Thanks

Comment: You might read about `AccessDecisionVoter` to make `ConsensusBased` decisions.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, you can. Parameters can be accessed as Spring EL variables. In fact the reference manual gives [several examples which use method parameters](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#el-pre-post-annotations). The class needs to be compiled with debug symbols present (which is usually the case).

Note that the annotation value is a single expressions string:

```
"(hasRole('BOOK_AIR') and #bookinType == 'AIR') or (hasRole('BOOK_BUS') and #bookinType='BUS')"
```

In practice, using complicated expressions is rather error-prone. You could also use a simpler expression, something like

```
"@accessChecker.check('book', #bookinType)"
```

Where `accessChecker` is a bean in your application context with a "check" method which returns true or false depending on whether the supplied operation information is allowed (you can check the current user's roles by accessing the security context yourself - you'll find that discussed elsewhere on SO).

You could also look into writing your own `AccessDecisionManager` or `AccessDecisionVoter` and plugin the functionality there, but that requires more internal knowledge.

Comment: the advice on how _error-prone_ Spring EL is and how to avoid it, is **invaluable**. +10 for that! thnx

Comment: I was getting an error because my method was void, one hour to see that. Thanks for "method which returns true or false depending"